# 401 Unauthorized Error Angular 5

Tags: spring, angular, oauth-2.0, angular5

```
obtainAccessToken(loginData){
        let params=new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('grant_type','password');
        params.append('username',loginData.username);
        params.append('password',loginData.password);
        params.append('client_id','myid');
        console.log(params.toString());
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('content_type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        headers.append('Authorization','Basic '+btoa("myid:mypaasword"));
        console.log(headers)
        let options=new RequestOptions({headers:headers});
        console.log(options);
        this._http.post('...../oauth/token',params.toString(),options)
            .pipe(map(res=>res.json(),err=>console.log(err)))
            .subscribe(
                data=>this.saveToken(data),
                err=>alert('Invalid Credials')
            );
        }
```

I always get 401 Unauthorized error when sending post request to get access to my spring app  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUmg5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't come from Spring. It's a Browser security.
I suppose your spring server is on another port than your frontend server (or another IP ?).

The browser doesn't allow to do ajax requests to another port/IP (for security reasons). It's called CORS :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

On the server side, you must add headers to your HttpServletResponse to explicit allow your client domain to request your server.

Comment: i really don't get it .I'm new with spring oauth and it's the first time that i use it,what i have to do exactly. How to add headers to HttpServletResponse?

Comment: Hello, be sure it's really CORS the problem (your ports are different on the client and the server). You can check this by trying to do exactly the same request with curl or postman. If you get the same error, CORS is your problem.
You can found documentation about implementing CORS in spring here : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: No it's working with postman and the server send me an access token. The client and the server are working in different ports. I don't think that the problem is from CORS because i added @CrossOrigin("*") to my restControllerClass.

Comment: No, as you describe it, it is CORS. @CrossOrigin("*") must not work, another browser security, it doesn't allow to authorize all origins. Check your response headers in Chrome to see if the response is correct.

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization, content_type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ..........
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 30 Jul 2018 09:46:05 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="oauth2/client"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

Comment: yes the same error Request URL: ...../oauth/token
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: [::1]:8090
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Answer (score 0):

Add cors plugin to your browser

firefox--> https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/

chrome--> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Switch off plugin and again switch on it.

If it works then problem is with your rest api.
add @crossorigin() in your controller
Follow this links:
https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/webmvc/spring-mvc-cors-configuration/
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: Try using this @CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200", allowedHeaders="*", methods={RequestMethod.POST})

Comment: i tried it ,but the same problem. I'm using a proxy with angular now but it return error 400 bad request

Comment: For http request in angular what are you using HttpClient or http??

Comment: i'm using http but i tried using httpclient and it's the same problem

Comment: can you share code it would be helpful to track down the issue